# iOS 11+ Navigation Bar's buttons and title not changing on pushed view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have 2 view controllers. View Controller A** and **View Controller B**

I want to achieve a very simple thing. Setting left and right navigation bar buttons on **View Controller A** and change title and and left navigation bar button on **View Controller B** when **B** is pushed.

I design **View Controller A** as I wanted but I cannot change anything including title on *pushed* **View Controller B**.

Here is the code I implemented;

*in viewdidLoad of A:*

```
    title = "Satışlarını Hızlandır!"
    let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "boostCloseIcon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(closeButtonTapped))
    leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = .black
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem

    let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "infoIcon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(infoButtonTapped))
    rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = .black
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

*in viewDidLoad of B:*

```
    title = "Confirmation"
    let backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "infoIcon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped))
    backBarButtonItem.tintColor = .black
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(backBarButtonItem, animated: false)
```

Comment: Try setting `title` in `viewWillAppear`. Try setting `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem...` in Controller A.

Comment: Already tried :/